# Synchronous network wrapper for nodeJs

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

Is it possible to read TCP/IP socket synchronously on nodeJs?

I have lots of trade orders that should be sent via TCP/IP to FIX server. I need to sent next order only after previous has been received, so it's a bit oncomfortable to handle responses via socket.on('data'). I will have to make too many loops, listening and writing.

What I'm trying to do is :
send order -> read socket in loop for correct response -> send next order

So the question is - how do I directly read TCP/IP socket in nodeJs without event hadlers?

Comment: Just make a list of pending orders to send, and send a new one each time you get the response for the last one.  This is only one level of callbacks.  If you can't do this, you shouldn't use Node.js.

Comment: I can do that, but it's a bad solution for many reasons. It should be possible to read TCP/IP socket directly, without "net" wrapper. As far as understand, "net" reads socket directly and fires an event when founds any data in socket. So it should be possible to connect to socket and read it at any time, waiting for right response.

Comment: @ProstoTrader No, it isn't a bad solution.  It is the right solution.  Also, why would you not want to use the `net` package?  You wish to reinvent all of it yourself?

Comment: I don't want to reinvent, I'm trying to find way to directly read socket. It's possible in c#, it's possible in PHP, why it is so complicated in nodeJs? I've tryed to google, but there is eventually only one built-in "net" package and zero info on how to read socket directly.

Comment: Right, so Node.js is simply the wrong tool for your intended design.  Don't use it, it does not fit.  Or use it and embrace its philosophy of asynchronous programming.  I know you will want to resist this advice, but the sooner you give in the sooner you will make forward progress.  Up to you.